# What is the term for summing all of the elements of a vector to produce a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a specific term for turning a vector into a scalar by summing all of the elements of the vector? I am trying to describe a part of a model that requires this.

Comment: That's a question for the mathematics SE sites. What you're looking for is the dot product of your given vector with a unit vector of the same shape.

Comment: I wonder how having alternative names for "sum" might help you with your model description.

Comment: Less "an alternative" rather than if there is a term I was missing that is used to describe it. Similarly to describing something with matrix vs scalar notation.

Comment: @deemel I am not sure an "all-ones vector" is a "unit vector"

Comment: @Henry you're right, I mixed that up. Late hour, most likely

Answer (score 1):

One can describe the operation as global add pooling, similar to global average pooling used in convolutional neural networks. In your case, the input is 1D.